# Adjust colors of funnel plot_ly object

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I created a funnel plot object using plotly, please find my code below. This plot looks perfectly fine, except that I want the grey areas between the bars white and not grey as they are now.

Can anyone help me to adjust the color between the different orange bars?

```
library(plotly)

funnel_data <- data.frame(x = c(90, 75, 40, 20), 
                          y = c("Aided", "Familiarity", "Consideration", "Preference"))

funnel_plot <- funnel_data %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(type = "funnel",
            y = y,
            x = x,
            textposition = "inside",
            textinfo = "value",
            opacity = 1,
            marker = list(color = c("rgb(255,098,000)", "rgb(255,098,000)",
                                    "rgb(255,098,000)", "rgb(255,098,000)"), width=0), 
            textfont = list(family = "ING me", size = 14, color = "white"),
            connector = list(fillcolor =list(color="white"))) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Aided", "Familiarity", "Consideration", "Preference"),
                      tickfont =list(family = "ING me", size = 12, color = 'rgb(105, 105, 105)')),
         xaxis = list(tickfont =list(family = "ING me", size = 12, color = 'rgb(105, 105, 105)')),
         legend =list(textfont = list(family = "ING me", size = 12, color = 'rgb(105, 105, 105)')))
##
funnel_plot
```

Comment: Looking at the source code I am not sure why what you have doesn't work: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/traces/funnel/attributes.js#L83 It seems that there is a `fillcolor` argument which controls the connectors colors. I couldn't get it to work in plotly.js either (https://codepen.io/Mdoubledash/pen/VwedwLy) so it seems to be a bug from the source and not specific to R API.

Comment: Hi M, thanks a lot for trying tough. I re tried, but in my case it works. The connector lines are easy to adjust, but the grey bars in between not. It does not matter how I adjust the fillcolor argument, it does not change. I use plotly’ version 4.9.2. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear here.. No, the code produces the desired plot, but with grey between the (desired) orange ones. I still struggle to change this

Comment: Changing connector =F doesnt help either, the areas between the bars are still grey

Comment: Replace the connector line by: connector = list(fillcolor = c("white", "white", "white", "white"))) %>%